# What do you mean by (Class name) while declaring objects in Java - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have recently started with android devolopment in Java after learning the basics and I noticed a new way that objects were initialised. For example:

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
```

Here I would like to know what `(TextView)` means and why can't we initialise a object by a static method or the `new` keyword. Thank you!

**Edit**:

I would also like to know what happens when a superclass object is casted on a base class object (What propities are inherited)

Comment: It is called type casting. You can get more information in basic Java tutorials :)

Comment: So what exactly does `findViewById()` return

Comment: That's a different question entirely and you can find the answer [in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int)).

Comment: `findViewById()` returns a widget that was already created and is in the view hierarchy. If this line is coming from an activity, then most likely the view hierarchy was set up by a `setContentView()` call sometime before this `findViewById()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
```

The statement `findViewById(R.id.textbox)` returns a `View` object from your xml layout that the `Activity`(or `Fragment`) is inflating, but the variable `t` needs a `TextView` object so you have to **explicitly** cast it as a `TextView` object with the `(TextView)` expression.

> Why can't we initialise a object by a static method or the new
>   keyword.

You can create a `TextView` object wih the `new` keyword like `TextView t = new TextView(this)` but then you have to dynamically place it into your Activity.

Comment: So what happens to the properties of the `TextView` object when we cast a `View` objects in it?

Comment: The TextView object retains its properties as well as all the properties from the Vew class, considering that the TextView class already inherits from the View class.